# Counting elements in array template

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I wrote a template for a 2D array and devise a method that counts how many elements are in the array. However, the method doesnt return anything.

```
template <class T, int row, int column>
class array2d {
private:
    typedef T value;
    //typedef value * iterator;
    std::vector<T> array;
public:

    array2d() : array(row * column) {}
    explicit array2d( std::initializer_list<T> list) : array(list) {}

    constexpr T& length(){
        int cnt = 0;

        for (auto element : array)
            ++cnt;

        return cnt;
    }
```

Other methods properly return what i need. It seems that whem using an int, i can't use .size() because it returns an `unsigned long long int` and have decided to count the elements inside that `for`.

Comment: Undefined behavior! You are returning reference to local variable `cnt`. Drop reference. Also do not over-complicate this just use `arrat.size()`.

Comment: Don't return a reference to a local - return by value.   Also, why would the length of an `array2d<double>` be of type `double`?   Shouldn't it be an integral type?   And why not simply return `row *column` or `array.size()`?

Comment: Isn't the number of elements statically known? `row * column`? And Why use `std::vector` if you have static array. Why not `std::array<std::array, column>, row>`?

Comment: Also, you count with int but return T. And you already have array.size() so why iterate the vector?

Comment: btw you should include a complete example for questions asking about problems with code ([mre]). The function does return something, just not what you expect it to return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T&` is a very bad choice of return type. You get UB from returning reference to local object and what if I use your `array2d` with `double` type? Can I use `array2d` with non-arithmetic type?

Return `std::size_t` instead.

```
std::size_t length(){
    return array.size();
}
```

Comment: I've used T& because this is what the author uses in [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Modern-Challenge-programmer-real-world-problems/dp/1788993861).

He defined most methods like `constexpr T const & operator() (size_t const r, size_t const c) const { return arr[r*column + c]; }`

Comment: @xampierre It makes sense for access to element of array, because they are of type `T` and reference grants access to the actual element, not a copy. But for `size()`... Let's say I use your class and have `array2d<double> myArray;`. Do you think it's right if I ask for `myArray.length()` and get `24.99` in return? About returning by reference, this only makes sense if the object outlives the reference. In practice, it's almost exclusively done when returning members of a class or parameter (like in `operator<<`). Here you want to return a local variable, not a class member.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to not use `size()`. The preferred type would be std::size_t, but as such you can choose what type suits you the best:

```
auto length()
{
  return (your_type_t) array.size();
}
```

Comment: code only answers are not nice. Can you explain why this is correct or what is wrong with OPs code?

Comment: you miss to explain why OPs code is wrong, so it isnt clear how yours is "better". The question is not about `size()`

Comment: OPs code doesn't compile. It may aswell explode the computer since it's UB.

Comment: I can't seem to see a general direction OP is trying to get to. The question needs to be clarified with a minimally reproducible example.

Comment: what is UB in OPs code? If you refer to returning the reference, then that is not UB. Only using the reference would be, so yes I completely agree the question as written cannot be answered without complete example